# perl - use of unintialized value in concatenation (.) or at string error

Tags: perl

Why printing an array is giving me an unitialized error in below code? 
 Could you please let me know what is the wrong here:

```
my $test = 1234.test.csv;

my @array = split '.', $test;

print $array[0];
```

the above print line is giving me an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You can refer `perldoc -f split`

```
my $test = "1234.test.csv"; #I don't know actual input

my @array = split/\./, $test; #split /PATTERN/,EXPR,LIMIT

print $array[0]; #Prints the first element `0` value `1234`
```

Answer (score 10):

After fixing your code by adding quotes

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $test = '1234.test.csv';

my @array = split '.', $test;
print $array[0];
```

I'm getting the same warning (yes, it's not an error).

The reason is that the first argument to [split](http://p3rl.org/split) is a regular expression, not a string. If you provide a string, it's converted to a regex. `.` in a regex matches any character, so the string gets split into empty spaces between all the characters. Trailing empty fields are stripped, though, as no LIMIT argument has been provided, so the array remains empty.

Backslash the dot to make it match literally:

```
my @array = split /\./, $test;
```